# Run perl script from python

Tags: python, windows, perl

I know there are some topic on Stack Overflow about this. But none of these make any sense to me. I am new to both python and perl and trying my best to understand. I would like to run a perl script from a piece of python code.

executing the perl script in command prompt goes as following:

```
perl perlscript.pl input.bopt7 output.xml
```

I would like to run this command from my python code.
I have tried the following:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perlscript.pl" , "input.bopt7" , "output.xml"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but this does not work. I get an error saying it is not a valid win32 ...

I need no input or output from this script. Just need to run it once.

Comment: Do you have PERL installed in Windows?

Comment: I can run the perl script from the windows command prompt so I guess perl is instaleld.

Comment: The command you're running in your command prompt is different from the one you're running in `Popen` --  the former runs `perl` and passes the script as an argument, the latter attempts to execute the script itself. Have you tried `Popen(["perl", "perlscript.pl", "input.bopt7", "output.xml"], ...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `perl` command itself when executing a perl script:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "perlscript.pl" , "input.bopt7" , "output.xml"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You did the same thing on the command line prompt; the `Popen` class cannot guess from the `perlscript.pl` file that you wanted to run this script with Perl. :-)

Comment: The error is now gone. The script looks to be executing (command prompt opens shortly) but the output.xml file is not created... (which is normally does when running this script in command prompt)

Comment: Are you sure `perlscript.pl` is in the same directory as this python script? Pass the full path to it, along with `input.bopt7`

Comment: It could be that it should be `perl.exe`; or that you need to specify the full path. My Windows idioms are a little rusty. Also make sure your paths are fully specified.

Comment: side question: how can I make my program wait till the script is fully executed. Now the program continue before the output.xml is created.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add perl to Popen arguments (just as you do on the command line)?

> pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "perlscript.pl" , "input.bopt7" , "output.xml"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

In your example, Windows tries to execute "perlscript.pl" as a Win32 executable, since this is the first parameter you specified, and fails because it doesn't contain the proper binary header (since it is a text file).

Answer (score 0):

The first argument should be `perl.exe`, if `perl.exe` is in your `PATH`; or the full path to the executable as all the rest are arguments to `perl.exe`.

Also make sure you put the full path for `perlscript.pl` and `input.bopt7`.